True Crime Series
I cannot find the name of the true crime series aired probably between 2013-2016... I remember little bits of 3 of the stories. 
All of the stories I believe were based between 1950 and 1960 ( and it's NOT A crime to Remember) 

Young envied teen with blonde hair is at a drive in and afterwards everyone is supposed to go to a party, she ends up missing and then found dead. It ends up it was some 'loner' guy that hung out in the same area (a popular street where teens met up) who killed her. 
Next story, 2 young girls stop by a (candy shop, or ice cream shop) on their way home from school, then walk home. As they are walking one girls house is closer so she goes home, the other is going to walk the rest of the way by herself and hears something behind her on a 'bridge' and she is abducted and killed.
Middle aged male live with family in a modest home and he and his wife do not get along. He kills her and hides her in his basement. Later through a tip, the cops find her remains under the concrete floor of the basement. 
That's all I have. If ANYONE can direct me to where I can find these episodes, please let me know!  Thanks you!


You might want to provide a more descriptive question title.

To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you watched the TV show (even an approximate year or decade is helpful), and what TV shows you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.
